# QCustomPlot como redimensionar gráfico?

Tags: c++, qt, histograma

Estou tentando fazer um histograma de repetição de 255 eventos, não sei qual é a quantidade máxima de vezes que esse evento pode ocorrer!

Tenho um *array* de *255* elementos, já com a quantidade de repetições dos eventos e quero mostrar isso no gráfico usando o `QCustomPlot`, mas o tamanho que é *4.8, 4.8*, e meu histograma bate em *23079* ou mais, talvez bem mais.

Como fazer para aumentar esse *4.8, 4.8* e deixar o gráfico bem de longe?

Segue parte do código:

```
int grayScale[255] = {0};

//faco meus bang pra montar o array
QVector<double> x(255),y(255);
ui->customPlot->addGraph();
for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    x[i] = i;
    y[i] = grayScale[i];
}
ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("Tom");
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("Quantidade");
ui->customPlot->replot();
```

Aguardo e agradeço desde já!

Comment: O método [`QCustomPlot::resizeEvent`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCustomPlot.html#a13e05523a40c3f08875df5cde85cf0d9) deve servir neste caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente a escala do gráfico deveria ser determinada automaticamente de modo a que todos os valores sejam visiveis. Aparentemente, no teu caso, isto não está a acontecer.

Podes forçar uma escala usando o método `setRange(int x, int y)`. No teu caso podes tentar:

```
int grayScale[255] = {0};

//faco meus bang pra montar o array
QVector<double> x(255),y(255);
ui->customPlot->addGraph();
for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    x[i] = i;
    y[i] = grayScale[i];
}
ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("Tom");
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("Quantidade");

ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(0, 255); 
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, 23079); // aqui deves alterar para o valor máximo no teu universo, por exemplo, guardando o valor numa variável `ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, maxGrayScale);` 

ui->customPlot->replot();
```